# Why does Hibernate return random result?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to read data from a database using Hibernate. I want to start from first row, read 200 rows and process them, then read the next 200 rows. But Hibernate returns a random row every time.

This method reads from the database.

```
public List getPages(int start, int end) {
    Criteria queryCriteria = session.createCriteria(Page.class);
    queryCriteria.setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(end);
    return queryCriteria.list();
}

public void MyFunction(){
    while (readFlag) {

        //get page from database;
        List<Page> pagesList = database.getPages(startFromDatabaseIndex,
                    READ_FROM_DATABASE_SIZE);

        if ((pagesList == null) || (pagesList.size() == 0)) {
            break;
        }
        if (pagesList.size() < READ_FROM_DATABASE_SIZE) {
                readFlag = false;
        } else {
            startFromDatabaseIndex = startFromDatabaseIndex + 200;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < pagesList.size(); i++) {
             process();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `But Hibernate return random row evry time` what do you mean by that??

Comment: What is the _query_ you're executing? Unless you explicitly specify an ordering, the data will be returned in arbitrary order. That's how RDBMS work; nothing to do with Hibernate, per se.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To extract data from a database using pagination you need to define a sort criteria based on wich you can define what you mean for first 200 rows, otherwise your database (not hibernate) will return 200 rows in an order that is not defined by you and that can change after some modification of data on the database.

Comment: Thank you, it works . I add this code to my code : 
queryCriteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
How can I retrive rows in my added order?

Comment: If the id is not equivalent to the insertion order You can add a create timestamp and use it to retrieve the data. In this case sort by two fields, first create_timestamp than id to be sure that if two records have the same creation timestamp you haven't problems